# What is wrong with my breadth first search algorithm, it crashes with a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, breadth-first-search

When I run my code it throws a segmentation fault and I have tried rewriting the code several times. Still to no avail, it won't even run. The segmentation fault happens as soon as my program is launched. What it's supposed to do is print a path on screen using the ncurses library in Linux, from the given coordinates. Here is the problematic snippet with the lines where gdb said the segmentation fault was, also it (snippet) reproduces the problem.

EDIT: This will help explain what I'm trying to do, but using dynamic arrays. [Breadth First Search](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html#python-breadth-first)

EDIT 2: The variable frontier is supposed to keep track of the X and Y values at a specific index. The add_neighbors function is there to add all four neighbors (providing they aren't already added) to the frontier and came_from arrays.

frontier[index][0] is X value.
frontier[index][1] is Y value.

The before the first while loop I set the start position x1 and y1. During the first while loop, it increments getting the new coordinates from the frontier, then processing and adding to came_from array.

For example:
(x1,y1)    (x1+1,y1)
(x1,y1+1)  (x1+1,y1+1)
(x1,y2)    (x2,y2)

I'm trying to get from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). Sure hope that explains it better. What I'm trying to implement is a Breadth First Search (BFS) algorithm. Using two arrays, one is frontier (keeps track of visited positions) and came_from (keeps track of X and Y the path from x1,y1 to x2,y2). Updated the code to reflect the first answer. Plus added a comment to explain where the error might be, not really sure but I've been debugging it. It looks like the came_from array never gets set with x and y.

The Code:

```
/*
 * pathfind.c - Simple Breadth First Search algorithm implementation.
 *
 * Author: Philip R. Simonson
 * Date  : 05/17/2021
 *
 ****************************************************************************
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
    
#define MAXHEIGHT 24
#define MAXWIDTH 80

/* Add neighboring positions to the arrays.
 */
int add_neighbors(int **frontier, int ***came_from, int count, int x, int y)
{
    // North
    if(y > 0 && came_from[y - 1][x][0] < 0) {
        frontier[count][0] = x;
        frontier[count][1] = y;
        count++;
        came_from[y - 1][x][0] = x;
        came_from[y - 1][x][1] = y;
    }
    // South
    if(y < MAXHEIGHT-1 && came_from[y + 1][x][0] < 0) {
        frontier[count][0] = x;
        frontier[count][1] = y;
        count++;
        came_from[y + 1][x][0] = x;
        came_from[y + 1][x][1] = y;
    }
    // West
    if(x > 0 && came_from[y][x - 1][0] < 0) {
        frontier[count][0] = x;
        frontier[count][1] = y;
        count++;
        came_from[y][x - 1][0] = x;
        came_from[y][x - 1][1] = y;
    }
    // East
    if(x < MAXWIDTH-1 && came_from[y][x + 1][0] < 0) {
        frontier[count][0] = x;
        frontier[count][1] = y;
        count++;
        came_from[y][x + 1][0] = x;
        came_from[y][x + 1][1] = y;
    }
    return count; // Return counter for frontier
}
/* Simple BFS algorithm for path finding.
 */
void path_finding(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int **frontier, ***came_from;
    int index, count;
    int i, j;

    index = 0;
    count = 0;

    // Initialise frontier array
    frontier = malloc(sizeof(int *) * MAXHEIGHT * MAXWIDTH);
    for(i = 0; i < (MAXHEIGHT * MAXWIDTH); i++) {
        frontier[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    }

    // Create came_from array
    came_from = malloc(sizeof(int **) * MAXHEIGHT);
    for(i = 0; i < MAXHEIGHT; i++) {
        came_from[i] = malloc(sizeof(int *) * MAXWIDTH);
        for(j = 0; j < MAXWIDTH; j++) {
            came_from[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
            came_from[i][j][0] = -1;
            came_from[i][j][1] = -1;
        }
    }

    // Add start to came_from
    came_from[y1][x1][0] = -9;
    came_from[y1][x1][1] = -9;

    // Add start to frontier
    frontier[count][0] = x1;
    frontier[count][1] = y1;
    count++;

    while(index < count) {
        int x = frontier[index][0];
        int y = frontier[index][1];
        index++;

        if(x == x2 && y == y2)
            break;

        count = add_neighbors(frontier, came_from, count, x, y);
    }

    // Set temp position variables to end position
    {
        int x = x2;
        int y = y2;

        while(x != x1 || y != y1) {
            int tempy = y;
            mvprintw(y, x, "*");
            // Segmentation fault because came_from[tempy][x][1] and came_from[tempy][x][0]
            // always equals -1 which is out of bounds. Not sure how to fix it, something
            // is wrong with add_neighbors function I think.
            y = came_from[tempy][x][1];
            x = came_from[tempy][x][0];
        }
    }

    // TODO: Return came_from array!

    // Free all resources from both arrays
    for(i = 0; i < MAXHEIGHT; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < MAXWIDTH; j++) {
            free(came_from[i][j]);
        }
        free(came_from[i]);
    }
    free(came_from);
    for(i = 0; i < (MAXHEIGHT * MAXWIDTH); i++) {
        free(frontier[i]);
    }
    free(frontier);
}

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    clear();

    path_finding(0, 2, 7, 8);

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with: cc -o test test.c -lncurses

GDB output:

```
[philip@darkstar temp]$ gdb --batch --ex r --ex bt --ex q temp

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
                                                    0x000055555555599d in path_finding (x1=0, y1=2, x2=7, y2=8) at src/pathfind.c:117
117             y = came_from[tempy][x][1];
#0  0x000055555555599d in path_finding (x1=0, y1=2, x2=7, y2=8) at src/pathfind.c:117
#1  0x00005555555551ff in main () at src/main.c:11
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 65294] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
[philip@darkstar temp]$
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn to better use the debugger. Can you print out the values of `tempy` and `x` when the segfault appears? (`p tempy`, `p x`). Try stepping through the code line by line (`b pathfind.c:114` to place a breakpoint before running, then `n` to step to the next line).

Comment: Wrong allocation size.  Suggest idiom `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n);`.  Certainly other issues too.

Comment: `if(x <= MAXWIDTH && came_from[y][x + 1][0] < 0) {` suspicious.  `x <= MAXWIDTH ... came_from[y][x + 1]...` looks out of range.

Comment: Okay did (b pathfind.c:117) in gdb and stepped through looking at x and y variables before setting x = x2 and y = y2. But after those two statement in the code, the variables equal -1 (both variables). So before the second while loop where the segment fault occurs. x = -1 and y = -1.

Comment: Despite its use as such in other languages, `assert` is not an error checking mechanism.  `assert( malloc() != NULL)` is bad practice.  It communicates to the reader that the author of the code believes that it is impossible for malloc to fail.

Comment: Part of the problem is that your variable names are very uninformative. I've spent some time looking over your code and it's still not clear to me what `frontier` represents, nor what `add_neighbors(...)` is intended to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the allocation sizes are incorrect:

- `frontier = malloc(sizeof(frontier) * MAXHEIGHT * MAXWIDTH);` should be

  ```
  frontier = malloc(sizeof(*frontier) * MAXHEIGHT * MAXWIDTH);
  ```
- `frontier[i] = malloc(sizeof(*frontier) * 2);` should read:

  ```
  frontier[i] = malloc(sizeof(frontier[i][0]) * 2);
  ```

These accesses are not properly protected:

- `if(y <= MAXHEIGHT && came_from[y + 1][x][0] < 0)` should be

  ```
   if (y < MAXHEIGHT-1 && came_from[y + 1][x][0] < 0)
  ```
- `if(x <= MAXWIDTH && came_from[y][x + 1][0] < 0)` should be

  ```
   if(x < MAXWIDTH-1 && came_from[y][x + 1][0] < 0)
  ```
- the `frontier` array is not initialized. You should use `calloc()` to intialize the `int` arrays to `0` or run an initialization loop.
- in the `while (x != x1 || y != y1)` loop, when you read `y = came_from[tempy][x][1]` you do not check that `y >= 0`. Since you initialized `came_from[y1][x1][0] = -9;` it way be negative and cause an out of bounds access during the next iteration as you set `tempy = y`.
- the algorithm is not obvious from the code, you might want to comment more for the reader's sake.

Comment: Well after fixing all those problems, it still had a segmentation fault. But I figured out where the problem lies I think. It isn't adding the neighbors (all four positions around the starting position and so on).